# Methodology to solve trigonometric equations such as $4x+\tan(x)=\pi$

Tags: trigonometry, numerical-methods, approximation

I have to solve the following trigonometric equation:

$$ 4\cdot \arctan(\omega_{180}) \ + \ \omega_{180} \ = \ \pi $$
which by setting $\arctan(\omega_{180}) = x$ becomes:

$$ 4x \ + \ \tan(x) \ - \ \pi \ = \ 0 $$

In order to solve the latter equation in terms of $x$, I tried to replace the term of $\tan(x)$ by the Taylor series approximation of $\sin(x), \cos(x)$ using only the first two terms but the derived results were not correct. Anyway, I used MATLAB to solve it and it did solved it. The correct result is:

$$ x = 0.61048 \Rightarrow \omega_{180} = 0.7 \text{rad/sec} $$

What I would like to ask is in which ways can I solve this equation by hand ? I don't want a complete solution as an answer but rather the methodologies I could study and then apply in such trigonometric equations.

Comment: What is the meaning of $\omega_{180}$?

Comment: The frequency where the phase diagram of a loop transfer function $L(s)$ crosses the -180deg line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is transcendental, there is no explicit expression for the zero of function
$$f(x)=4x+\tan(x)-\pi$$ and numerical methods (or *approximations*) are required.

Being very lazy, expand $f(x)$ as a series around $x=0$ and obtain
$$f(x)=-\pi +5 x+\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{2 x^5}{15}+\frac{17 x^7}{315}+\frac{62
   x^9}{2835}+\frac{1382 x^{11}}{155925}+O\left(x^{13}\right)$$

Now, using series reversion,
$$x=t-\frac{t^3}{15}-\frac{t^5}{75}-\frac{t^7}{7875}+\frac{67 t^9}{70875}+\frac{5017
   t^{11}}{19490625}+O\left(t^{13}\right)$$ where $t=\frac{f(x)+\pi}{5}$. Since we desire $f(x)=0$ then $t=\frac \pi 5$. Replacing, the estimate is then
$$x \sim \color{red}{0.610487}235$$ while the exact solution given by Newton method is         $0.610487119$

Just for the fun of doing it *almost* by hand, all of the above was done using my $50$ years old non-programmable calculator.

Comment: Is that a HP, a TI or an Omron?

Comment: @Deepak. It is an HP 20S  I bought in 1974

Comment: Newton's Method will work well, with an initial approximation $x_1=\pi /4$ because $ f(0)<0<f(\pi /4)$, and $f'$ & $f''$ are positive on $[0,\pi /4].$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet. For sure ! Start with $x_0=0$ to get x_1=\frac \pi 5$. I did not want to address numerical methods. Cheers and ***Happy New Year***

Comment: Nice! I'm (literally) dating myself, but 1974 was the year of my birth lol. My first (and sadly, only) HP calculator was the 42S I received as first prize in the national HP tech quiz when I was in junior college (senior high school) in 1991. Loved that thing to bits, RPN and all. But even before that, I had used an ancient RPN LED Omron scientific calculator inherited from my father, which should belong to roughly the same era as your HP 20S.

Comment: @Deepak. Just to give you an idea : in 1974, the price of that HP 20S was ...250 USD of that time  which correspond to 1410 USD today !!!!

Comment: Yes, but I'm sure a fully working model is worth more to collectors now.

Comment: @Deepak. If you want it, start an auction !!!

Comment: Lol............